# How to add site template into Organizations template library with lists and data?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-template, site

I am trying to build a site template which will contains few lists and data within the list.

I am aware that I can create site script and add all lists and libraries, but that site scripts doesn't allow to create a site with data.

Is there any way by which I can create a site template and add it to the organization templates so that it can be available to every one in the organization?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you enable custom script for your sitecollection you get the option "Save site as template".

It has an option to save content. I don't know if it will show up under your organization.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That in this case, if the site contains any SPFx webpart, it won't allow us to save the site as template